# What is the current policy for autoplay feature on Google Chrome for Android?

Tags: android, google-chrome, html5-video

I'm trying to make a html5 video element be autoplayed among the major browsers. Can't find any resource describing the current autoplay policy on Chrome.

On iOS, webkit.org published [New  Policies for iOS](https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/) at **Jul 25, 2016**.

On Google for Android, Google published [Muted Autoplay on Mobile: Say Goodbye to Canvas Hacks and Animated GIFs!](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/07/autoplay) at **Jul, 2016 for version 53**. 
Unfortunately this is not working on current version (55).

Comment: Did you find this: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/07/autoplay

Comment: Hey @MorrisonChang! I did read this article and update the question description. Unfortunately this is not working on current version (55). :/

Comment: I went to Chromium's bug list for autoplay https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list?can=2&q=autoplay+android&colspec=ID+Pri+M+Stars+ReleaseBlock+Component+Status+Owner+Summary+OS+Modified&x=m&y=releaseblock&cells=ids and saw a number of issues Not sure if you knew about it before but worth looking to see if already triaged.